# Why is this background-image darkened in mozilla?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, background-image

```
<div class="controlbar">
    <div class="nav_gallery"></div>
</div>

.controlbar {
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    min-height:360px;
    width:128px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:#C8B43C;
    box-shadow:#151416 0px 0px 0px 1px, #101010 0px 0px 4px 1px;
}

.nav_gallery {
    position:absolute;
    width:134px;
    height:50px;
    top:128px;
    left:0px;
    background-image:url("css/nav_selected.png"); <------
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

How come the background-image appears darkened in mozilla firefox, and what can I do to fix that? I've tried searching for it but nothing came up.

Here's an example image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE1lL.png

Comment: does your background image has alpha transparency? which format is (PNG8, PNG24, PNG32)?

Comment: Yeah I came across this earlier. I was going to wait until tomorrow to post an answer since I don't have enough reputation to post it before 8 hours. But apparently it has to do with the actual png file. I noticed that the divs with jpg background-images didn't appear darkened, and then I remembered I had saved those jpgs in photoshop, and these pngs in paint.net. So I resaved the pngs from paint.net in photoshop instead and sure enough that did the trick. And to answer your question, it was a PNG24 saved in paint.net.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the px after any 0 values. Additionally, since this is a gecko problem you should be sure your browser is updated.

Comment: I installed Firefox today, just to make sure the website looks alright in all browsers, so I guess I must have the latest version already. Is there any particular reason why I should remove the px after 0 values? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Adding units to 0 measurements is unnecessary. Theoretically it's not the same as zero even though it is likely to be treated as such.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why I was getting darkened images in firefox.

I compared the pngs that were darkened to my jpgs that weren't, and then I remembered that I had saved the jpgs in photoshop, and the pngs as 24bit ones in paint.net. So I put them in photoshop and re-saved them as pngs and sure enough it worked.

Oh well, there it is if anyone has had the same problem.

It's still weird that I had this issue in Mozilla Firefox but not in Google Chrome or Microsoft Explorer. If anyone knows the reason of that please leave a comment.